# Unable to access a arXiv URL using Selenium WebDriver in a GitHub Actions workflow

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, github-actions

I'm trying to automate a process in Python using Selenium WebDriver where I need to access the URL [https://arxiv.org/pdf/2305.11169.pdf"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2305.11169.pdf%22) inside of a GitHub workflow. The problem is that the site doesn't seem to load when accessed via the workflow. Instead, I get the URL `data:,` and the page content is `<html><head></head><body></body></html>`.

Here's how I've set up my WebDriver:

```py
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36')
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
```

And here's the relevant part of my script:

```py
def test():
    driver.get("https://arxiv.org/pdf/2305.11169.pdf")
    time.sleep(10)
    url = driver.current_url
    print("url", url)
    content = driver.page_source
    print(content)
```

The GitHub Actions workflow is set up like this:

```yaml
name: Post
on:
  schedule:
    - cron: '0 0 * * *'  # This will run the workflow every day at 12 AM UTC.
  workflow_dispatch:  
jobs:
  scrape:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Check out repository
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Set up Python
      uses: actions/setup-python@v2
      with:
        python-version: 3.8
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install -r requirements.txt
    - name: Run script
      run: python main.py
```

Can anyone suggest what might be the issue? Is there a limitation on GitHub Actions or Selenium WebDriver that I'm missing? Or could this be a specific issue with the site I'm trying to access? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try increasing the sleep time?